# React.js Simple Numeric Input with Mask

Tags: react.js

I've a created a simple generic numeric input component with input mask which must only valid decimal numbers as input. Please check the code for any improvements.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PatternConstants from '../Constants/PatternConstants.js';

const NumericInput = (props) => {

   const pattern = props.pattern ?? PatternConstants.NUMERIC_INPUT_PATTERN;
   const regexPattern = new RegExp(pattern);
   const initValue = regexPattern.test(props.value) ? props.value : '';
   const [inputValue, updateInputValue] = useState(initValue);

   const onInputChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;

        if (value.charAt(value.length - 1) === '.' && value.match(PatternConstants.NUMERIC_INPUT_LAST_DOT_PATTERN)?.length < 2) {
            updateInputValue(value);
        }

        if (value === '' || regexPattern.test(value)) {
            updateInputValue(value);
        }
    }

    return (
            <input type="text" 
                placeholder="Test" 
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={(event) => onInputChange(event)} />
    )
}

export default NumericInput;
```

**PatternConstants**

```
const PatternConstants = {
     NUMERIC_INPUT_PATTERN: /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/,
     NUMERIC_INPUT_LAST_DOT_PATTERN: /^[0-9]+(\.)$/,
}

export default PatternConstants;
```